# Log All API request and response + Slim framework

Tags: php, api, slim

I want to log every request and response for API.

```
$app->hook('slim.after.router', function () use ($app) { 
    $request = $app->request; 
    $response = $app->response;
    echo "<pre>";print_r($response);die;

});
```

Here i am getting proper request but when i tried to print out response i am getting

```
Slim\Http\Response Object
(
    [status:protected] => 200
    [headers] => Slim\Http\Headers Object
        (
            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [Content-Type] => application/json
                )

        )

    [cookies] => Slim\Http\Cookies Object
        (
            [defaults:protected] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 
                    [domain] => 
                    [path] => 
                    [expires] => 
                    [secure] => 
                    [httponly] => 
                )

            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [body:protected] => 
    [length:protected] => 0
)
```

I am able to render proper response in API response but not getting as in logs.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use of `slim.after` instead of `slim.after.router` have resolved the problem.

As in the [documentation](https://docs.slimframework.com/hooks/defaults/)

> **slim.after.router** :- This hook is invoked after the router is
>   dispatched, before the Response is sent to the client, and after
>   output buffering is turned off. This hook is invoked once during the
>   Slim application lifecycle.
>
> **slim.after** :- This hook is invoked after output buffering is turned off and after the Response is sent to the client. This hook is
>   invoked once during the Slim application lifecycle.

```
$app->hook('slim.after', function () use ($app) { 
    $request = $app->request; 
    $response = $app->response;
    echo "<pre>";print_r($request);die;
});
```

which outputs :-

```
Slim\Http\Response Object
(
    [status:protected] => 200
    [headers] => Slim\Http\Headers Object
        (
            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [Content-Type] => application/json
                )

        )

    [cookies] => Slim\Http\Cookies Object
        (
            [defaults:protected] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 
                    [domain] => 
                    [path] => 
                    [expires] => 
                    [secure] => 
                    [httponly] => 
                )

            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [body:protected] => {"data":{"Authorization":"786876866","user":{"id":"1","user_role":"1"}},"status":200,"success":true,"message":"user authentication successful"}
    [length:protected] => 577
)
```

Ofcourse you will get response object too :)